# URL rewrite using JQUERY and REGULAR EXPRESSIONS

Tags: javascript, regex

I browsed all the afternoon trying to find a good solution, but with no luck.

This is the problem:
I have an old html website. I have to change every link built in this way:

```
<a href="javascript: OpenImage('/dir1/dir2/Image321.jpg',' Image description ');void(0);">
```

with a standard a href:

```
<a href="/dir1/dir2/Image321.jpg" title="Image description">
```

I think I have have to look for href beginning with "avascript:"

```
$("a[href^='javascript:']")
```

and change it using regular expression..

But after thousands test I can't solve it..

Any idea?
thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use a find replace operation to actually fix the urls?

Comment: Why are you doing this? My next question would be why are you trying to do this with jQuery?

Comment: C Bauer: because I will have to do that for hundreds pages.

Comment: Salman A: because I want to use fancybox to open images instead of my old custom javascript (no more working in cross-browser). I think that jQuery is the best solution.. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this :**

```
var re = /(^<a\s*href=")javascript:\s*OpenImage\('(.*)'\s*,\s*'(.*)'([^<]+)">/gmi;
var str = '<a href="javascript: OpenImage(\'/dir1/dir2/Image321.jpg\',\' Image description \');void(0);">\n\n<a href="javascript: OpenImage(\'/dir1/dir2/Image321.jpg\',\' Image description \');void(0);"> djhjdh</a>\n\n<a href="javascript: OpenImage(\'/dir1/dir2/Image321.jpg\',\' Image description \');void(0);"><img src="asdf"></a>';
var subst = '\1\2" title="\3">';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC5wT9/4)

Comment: I marked it too early..there is a problem if after the string there is another "<" like: 
    <a href="javascript: OpenImage('/dir1/dir2/Image321.jpg',' Image description ');void(0);"> <img src="asdf"></a>

Answer (score 0):

```
(<a href=")[^']+'([^']+)','([^']+).*
```

Try this.Replace by `$1$2" title="$3">`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/14

```
var re = /(<a href=")[^']+'([^']+)','([^']+).*/gm;
var str = '<a href="javascript: OpenImage(\'/dir1/dir2/Image321.jpg\',\' Image description \');void(0);">';
var subst = '$1$2" title="$3">';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: it is wrong for case:`<a href="javascript: OpenImage('/dir1/dir2/Image321.jpg',' Image description ');void(0);">see</a>`